# echoing 'alt' attribute in image - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a gallery widget for wordpress -

I get the images fine, and the data is present.

```
function add_my_shortcode(){
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Byggeriet i billeder' );
//var_dump(get_field('gallery_repeater', $page->ID)[0]['rep_img']['url']);

$arrayOfImages = get_field('gallery_repeater', $page->ID);
if ($arrayOfImages) {
    $content = '';
    $order = array();
    //reverse the order of images
    foreach ($arrayOfImages as $key => $value) {
        $order[ $key ] = $key;
    }

    array_multisort( $order, SORT_DESC, $arrayOfImages );


    //$content .= '<p>Seneste fra galleriet</p>';
    foreach ($arrayOfImages as $key => $value) {

        if($key < 3){
            $img = $value['rep_img'];

            $desc = $value['rep_desc'];

            $url = $img['url'];
            $title = $img['title'];

            if($img['alt']){
                $alt = strip_tags($img['alt']);
            } else {
                $alt = strip_tags($desc);
            }


            //var_dump($alt);
            $caption = $img['caption'];
            $sizes = $img['sizes'];
            //var_dump($key." -> ".$url);
            //$content .= '<a title="gallery" href="/ombygning/byggeriet-i-billeder"><img class="sidebarGallery" src="'.$sizes['sachiko_4by3'].'" alt="'.$alt.'" ></a>';

            if(!$alt){
                $alt = "gallery image";
            }

            $content .= '<a title="gallery" href="/ombygning/byggeriet-i-billeder">';
            $content .= '<img class="sidebarGallery" src="'.$sizes['sachiko_4by3'].'" alt="'.$alt.'" >';
            $content .= '</a>';
             var_dump($alt);
            //returns : string(30) "Disse billeder er bare tests7 " string(30) "Disse billeder er bare tests6 " string(30) "Disse billeder er bare tests5 "

        }

    }

    return $content;
}


}

add_shortcode('galleryShortcode', 'add_my_shortcode');
```

When i var_dump the $alt, I see the values just fine - but it is NOT present in the displayed code - meaning that the data is fine, but i must be displaying it wrong somehow -

I don't know if it is a syntax error, but i have been starring myself blind at this - and it stands to reason that there is an obvious solution somewhere.

The code that is displayed comes out something like this :

```
<img title="" class="sidebarGallery" src="my-image-url-hidden.jpg" alt="">
```

Also don't know why that the img tag suddenly has a title attribute..

Earlier I had it all in one line, which had the same result .

Comment: Take a look at the page source in your  browser (not the developer tools). It possibly gets edited by some JavaScript.

Comment: The comment in the code seems a little strange to me.  How can `$alt` have three different string values?  Is it an array or something of that nature?

Comment: It is in a for loop - sry.

Comment: didn't want to include Tto much code - this is the relevant part

Comment: i guess you are looking in the wrong place, the title is empty and the class name is different from the one you posted in the question, so the output is all different than the code

Comment: include the whole code please !!

Comment: @Timino Let's keep it at an [mcve]. No need to paste complete projects into the question.

Comment: Inserted entire function - updated the strings to remove confusion.

Comment: If i echo it out, instead of returning it - it works fine. -_-

Comment: But i belive that return should be better to have in shortcode functions - any idea on how to make it work with return?

Comment: @Stender: What do you mean "echo it instead of return it"?  What is invoking this `add_my_shortcode` function?  Where is the `add_shortcode` function you're also referencing?  What else is all this code doing?  Can you provide a single example which simply replicates the problem?

Comment: @David In the bottom of the code - If i replace 'return' with 'echo', then it spits out the alts fine. the add_shortcode function is a core funtion in wordpress, the way i call the function is simply either calling echo do_shortcode('[galleryShortcode]') - or writing ['galleryShortcode'] in the wp editor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $alt is an array but does not show it as such. Try to put $alt[0] instead of $alt.

Comment: The $alt, is var dumped 3 times, it is strings, not an array. I have updated the question to show the entire function

Comment: It is possibly foolish but try to add a static value to alt to make sure the value is not replaced by another script, either php or javascript.Or maybe be a wrong code place.

Comment: it will not work with a static either - not unless i echo $content instead of return $content

Comment: **1.** if you insert alt="somthing" and its return a empty alt, means that you  are modifing a worong code.
**2.** Download sourcecode **view-source:** http://domain.tld/directory and verify that alt is o or not is empty.